# How to extract the name of immediate directory along with the filename?

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have a file whose complete path is like

```
/a/b/c/d/filename.txt
```

If I do a [`basename`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basename) on it, I get `filename.txt`. But this filename is not too unique.

So, it would be better if I could extract the filename as `d_filename.txt` i.e.

```
{immediate directory}_{basename result}
```

**How can I achieve this result?**

Comment: If you want to do this for many files, you'll need to provide more information. Like which directory the script should be ran in? Also, what do you want to do with the new filename once you create it? Assign it to a var? Rename the original file?

Comment: I am in the `root` directory. Yes, I want to assign it to a variable in my program. The problem is that the patch could even be `/a/b/c/anotherfile.txt` i.e. it is not fixed that the files are inside the fourth hierarchy.

Comment: Code updated to reflect this. Please see my answer here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340052/how-to-extract-the-name-of-immediate-directory-along-with-the-filename/2340469#2340469

Answer (score 2):

```
file="/path/to/filename"
echo $(basename $(dirname "$file")_$(basename "$file"))
```

or

```
file="/path/to/filename"
filename="${file##*/}"
dirname="${file%/*}"
dirname="${dirname##*/}"
filename="${dirname}_${filename}"
```

Comment: I have a lot of different files inside the folder hierarchy, so I don't know the name of the folders beforehand.

Comment: @eSKay: Stumbled upon this old question, but thought to point out that this answer does not depend on knowing the names beforehand; just change the `/path/to/filename` in either solution to the the path to your file and use the rest verbatim - it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

This code will recursively search through your hierarchy starting with the directory that you run the script in. I've coded the loop in such a way that it will handle any filename you throw at it; file names with spaces, newlines etc.

*Note**: the loop is currently written to ***not*** include any files in the directory that this script resides in, it only looks at subdirs below it.  This was done as it was the easiest way to make sure the script does not include itself in its processing. If for some reason you must include the directory the script resides in, it can be changed to accommodate this.

#### Code

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    dirpath="${file%/*}"
    filename="${file##*/}"
    temp="${dirpath}_${filename}"
    parent_file="${temp##*/}"

    printf "dir: %10s  orig: %10s  new: %10s\n" "$dirpath" "$filename" "$parent_file"
done < <(find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print0)
```

#### Test tree

```
$ tree -a
.
|-- a
|   |-- b
|   |   |-- bar
|   |   `-- c
|   |       |-- baz
|   |       `-- d
|   |           `-- blah
|   `-- foo
`-- parent_file.sh
```

#### Output

```
$ ./parent_file.sh
dir:  ./a/b/c/d  orig:       blah  new:     d_blah
dir:    ./a/b/c  orig:        baz  new:      c_baz
dir:      ./a/b  orig:        bar  new:      b_bar
dir:        ./a  orig:        foo  new:      a_foo
```

Comment: This will not always work. /a/1/b/c/d/baz and /a/2/b/c/d/baz wil yield duplicate the duplicate names 'd_baz'.

Comment: This is true, but I would say your comment would be more appropriate for the OP than myself as my code meets the requirements as stated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ FILE=/a/b/c/d/f.txt
$ echo $FILE
/a/b/c/d/f.txt
$ echo $(basename ${FILE%%$(basename $FILE)})_$(basename $FILE)
d_f.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

don't need to call external command

```
s="/a/b/c/d/filename.txt"
t=${s%/*}
t=${t##*/}
filename=${t}_${s##*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the example:

```
 /a/1/b/c/d/file.txt
 /a/2/b/c/d/file.txt
```

The only reliable way to qualify `file.txt` and avoid conflicts is to build the entire path into the new filename, e.g.

```
 /a/1/b/c/d/file.txt -> a_1_b_c_d_file.txt
 /a/2/b/c/d/file.txt -> a_2_b_c_d_file.txt
```

You may be able to skip part of the beginning if you know for sure that it will be common to all files, e.g if you know that all files reside somewhere underneath the directory `/a` above:

```
 /a/1/b/c/d/file.txt -> 1_b_c_d_file.txt
 /a/2/b/c/d/file.txt -> 2_b_c_d_file.txt
```

To achieve this on a per-file basis:

```
# file="/path/to/filename.txt"
new_file="`echo \"$file\" | sed -e 's:^/::' -e 's:/:_:g'`"
# new_file -> path_to_filename.txt
```

Say you want do do this recursively in a directory and its subdirectories:

```
# dir = /a/b
( cd "$dir" && find . | sed -e 's:^\./::' | while read file ; do
  new_file="`echo \"$file\" | sed -e 's:/:_:g'`"
  echo "rename $dir/$file to $new_file"
done )
```

Output:

```
rename /a/b/file.txt to file.txt
rename /a/b/c/file.txt to c_file.txt
rename /a/b/c/e/file.txt to c_e_file.txt
rename /a/b/d/e/file.txt to d_e_file.txt
...
```

The above is highly portable and will run on essentially any Unix system under any variant of `sh` (inclusing `bash`, `ksh` etc.)